issue with saving form data to the database using JavaScript in Laravel
i want to use  JavaScript to save js generated data  to a Laravel backend.
I'm creating a recipe generator using an API that also provides JavaScript code to generate and display recipes. I want to enhance it to save liked recipes to the backend. I've already set up the controller, recipe model, and migration, and successfully migrated the data. However, when I attempt to use the save button, I encounter an internal server error.
recipeGen:145
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/recipes/save 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @   recipeGen:145
recipeGen:159 There was a problem with the request: Error: Network response was not ok
at HTMLButtonElement. (recipeGen:154:27)
Contoller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Recipe;
class recipeGenController extends Controller
{
    public function indexRecipeGen()
    {
        return view('recipeGen.index');

    }
    public function save(Request $request)
{
    $recipe = new Recipe;

    $recipe->label = $request->input('label');
    $recipe->image = $request->input('image');
    $recipe->url = $request->input('url');
    $recipe->ingredients = json_encode($request->input('ingredients')); // Encode ingredients as JSON

    $recipe->save();

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Recipe saved successfully']);
}
}


View with js here i implemented the logic of saving the recipes using js
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid height">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="card text-white rounded-50" style="height: 350px;">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/08/24/bakery-1868396_1280.jpg" class="card-img w-90 shadow-lg" style="height: 350px; object-fit: cover; object-position: center 20%;" alt="...">
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <div class="card-body text-center w-75">
                        <h2 class="fw-bold text-center mb-4" style="border: 1px solid #fff; padding: 15px; border-radius: 15px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 24px;">What are you cooking today?</h2>
                        <form id="searchForm" class="input-group w-100">
                            <div class="position-relative w-100">
                                <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control form-input rounded-2 pr-5" style="height: 50px;" placeholder="Search ingredients" required>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded-2 position-absolute end-0 translate-middle-y" style="margin-right: 10px; bottom: -15px; font-size: 1rem" data-mdb-ripple-init>
                                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i> Search
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="results" class="row mt-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
const searchForm = document.querySelector('#searchForm');
const searchInput = document.querySelector('#search');
const resultsList = document.querySelector('#results');

searchForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    searchRecipes();
});

async function searchRecipes() {
    const searchValue = searchInput.value.trim();
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${searchValue}&app_id=c9c73e56&app_key=188f2d8ebf311601d1174c9af0ad0825`);
        if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        const data = await response.json();
        displayRecipes(data.hits);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching the recipes:', error);
    }
}

function displayRecipes(recipes) {
    let html = '';
    recipes.forEach((recipe, index) => {
        if (index % 4 === 0) {
            html += '<div class="row">';  // Creates a new row every 4 recipes
        }
        html += `
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="${recipe.recipe.image}" alt="${recipe.recipe.label}">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">${recipe.recipe.label}</h3>
                    <ul>
                        ${recipe.recipe.ingredientLines.map(ingredient => `<li>${ingredient}</li>`).join('')}
                    </ul>
                    <a href="${recipe.recipe.url}" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">View Recipe</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary save-btn" data-recipe-label="${recipe.recipe.label}" data-recipe-image="${recipe.recipe.image}" data-recipe-url="${recipe.recipe.url}" data-ingredients="${JSON.stringify(recipe.recipe.ingredientLines)}">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`;
        if ((index + 1) % 4 === 0 || index === recipes.length - 1) {
            html += '</div>';  // Closes the row after every 4 recipes or for the last row
        }
    });
    resultsList.innerHTML = html;

    // Add event listener for save button
    document.querySelectorAll('.save-btn').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
            const label = button.getAttribute('data-recipe-label');
            const image = button.getAttribute('data-recipe-image');
            const url = button.getAttribute('data-recipe-url');
            const ingredients = button.getAttribute('data-ingredients');
            try {
                const response = await fetch('/recipes/save', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ label, image, url, ingredients })
                });
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                const result = await response.json();
                console.log(result.message); // Log success message
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('There was a problem with the request:', error); // Log error message
            }
        });
    });
}

</script>
@endsection

Routes

<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\ArchiveController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RecipeGenController;
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/recipeGen', [RecipeGenController::class, 'indexRecipeGen'])->name('recipeGen');
Route::get('/editProfile', [App\Http\Controllers\userProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('editProfile');
Route::delete('/profile/destroy', [App\Http\Controllers\userProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');




Route::post('/recipes/save', [RecipeGenController::class, 'save'])->name('recipes.save');
Route::get('/recipes', [ArchiveController::class, 'index'])->name('recipes.index');


Model
<?php



namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Recipe extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['label', 'image', 'ingredients', 'url'];
}



Did you check the Laravel/server logs for more details?

use APP\Models\Recipe; Any specific reason you use APP here instead of App like everywhere else?

[RecipeGenController::class, 'index'] There doesn't seem to be an index method in your controller, you named it indexRecipeGen.

@Heize568, Typo.Change the Controller class name from recipeGenController to RecipeGenController

i corrected the mistake the size of the image url was too large to be saved
